# Appending a list inside np.array() does not work like doing it separately

Tags: python, list, numpy

I was hanging around with numpy, trying to create an array from a list that I faced something very strange.

```
list = [range(5), range(5)]
arr1 = np.array(list)
```

Now, if I say:

```
list.append(range(5))
arr2 = np.array(list)
```

everything works fine, however, if I directly say:

```
arr3 = np.array(list.append(range(5)))
```

it returns:

```
array(None, dtype=object)
```

Anyone knows what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list.append` doesn't return the list, it just performs the action and returns `None`.